# SSRS use Column Groups without creating new rows for each set?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to update an SSRS report that uses column groups to present detail rows from a database stored procedure.

The header rows are simple enough to hide duplicates, but the detail rows create a lot of empty white space that makes the report not suitable for a mail merge.

Is there any way to use SSRS table properties, or column group settings to not present subsequent detail column groups on a new row?

Each row should only have 1 order_no/customer, but a variable quantity of repeating column groups for items and prices.

SSRS Design:

|  |  | [items]*hidden columns group* |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| order_no | customer | item_name *Expression + "_1"* | item_price *Expression + "_1"* |
| [order_no] *duplicates hidden* | [customer] *duplicates hidden* | [item_name] | [price_price] |

Preview:

| order_no | customer | item_name_1 | item_price_1 | item_name_2 | item_price_2 | item_name_3 | item_price_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sally | book | 10.00 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | dvd | 20.00 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | book | 15.00 |
| 2 | Zhang | dvd | 50.00 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Steve | dvd | 50.00 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | book | 10.00 |  |  |

Goal:

| order_no | customer | item_name_1 | item_price_1 | item_name_2 | item_price_2 | item_name_3 | item_price_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sally | book | 10.00 | dvd | 20.00 | book | 15.00 |
| 2 | Zhang | dvd | 50.00 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Steve | dvd | 50.00 | book | 10.00 |  |  |

Comment: It looks like your ROW GROUP is grouping by too many fields. The row group (based on your sample) need to only group by order_no and customer.

Comment: Thank you Alan, it was the Row Group setting, but I think the group was not properly defined. I setup the row group again, and it fell into place. Thank you for the suggestion!